# MouseDragElementBehavior in UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I am currently porting an old game made for Windows Phone 8 in WPF/Silverlight to Universal Windows Platform. I have made letters that you can move in a canvas using MouseDragElementBehavior class. Is there any similar in UWP for this class?

Comment: Why dont you try ManipulationDelta event ?

Comment: I think I saw once a package in nugget that supposed to have wpf like behaviors for uwp projects

Answer (score 0):

There is an event called ManipulationDelta which is suggested in the comments. Here is how you can use it:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Canvas>
        <TextBlock
            FontSize="64"
            ManipulationDelta="LetterA_ManipulationDelta"
            ManipulationMode="All"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
            Text="A">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="dragLetterA" />
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock
            FontSize="64"
            ManipulationDelta="LetterB_ManipulationDelta"
            ManipulationMode="All"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
            Text="B">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="dragLetterB" />
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock
            FontSize="64"
            ManipulationDelta="LetterC_ManipulationDelta"
            ManipulationMode="All"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
            Text="C">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="dragLetterC" />
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Code behind looks like this:

```
private void LetterA_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dragLetterA.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    dragLetterA.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}

private void LetterB_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dragLetterB.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    dragLetterB.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}

private void LetterC_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dragLetterC.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    dragLetterC.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}
```

As simple as that.

Hope this helps.